# Event Hub Pointer w/ Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have asked this q on the microsoft docs, was then asked instead to post on msdn social forums, who then said i should post here...

So, consider that i have an EventHub, & something happens / errors during working with that message, does the pointer moved on regardless, or is the message now 'lost' ?

I am currently working on a project whereby we have an Azure Function w/ Event Hub trigger, and if that functions errors (for whatever reason).. how should the message that was currently being worked with?

Do we manually move the pointer back?

Comment: have a look at the following: https://hackernoon.com/reliable-event-processing-in-azure-functions-37054dc2d0fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Event Hubs are targeted at high throughput, so the default behavior is to ignore errors and move the pointer (checkpoint) further regardless.

The main workaround is basically catching exceptions and retrying / dead-lettering them manually.

Have a look at [Reliable Event Processing in Azure Functions](https://hackernoon.com/reliable-event-processing-in-azure-functions-37054dc2d0fc). It's a great article that covers the options available to you to avoid losing messages.

Comment: absolutely excellent blog.. it a) answered some of the questions i had, and b) offered some solutions - couldn't ask for much more! :)

Comment: sometimes, don't know why, i come and look at my old SO questions, and now realise why this blog is so good.. Jeff Hollan wrote it haha 